# Module export of pg-promise object derived from promise chain

Tags: pg-promise

We're using HashiCorp's Vault to store database connection credentials, then constructing the connection string for pg-promise from those. The 'catch' is that the Vault details are provided from a Promise wrapper, due to request callbacks to the Vault API.

Example database.js module:

```
const pgp = require('pg-promise')(/* options obj */);

const getDbo = () => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        vault.init().then(secrets => {
        let credentials = secrets.dbUser + ':' + secrets.dbPass
        let connStr = 'postgres://' + credentials + '<@endpoint/db>'
        let dbo = pgp(connStr, (err) => {
          reject(err)
        })
        resolve(dbo);
    })
    }
module.exports = { get: getDbo }
```

This is being imported in multiple routes. With this we are seeing the warning "WARNING: Creating a duplicate database object for the same connection." Is there a better way to resolve this so there is only one object per connection details?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382796/where-should-i-initialize-pg-promise. Also, unlcear what `pgp(connStr, (err) =>` means, the library only takes a connection string/object.

Comment: Thanks; edited for pgp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating and initializing a connection for [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) is a completely synchronous operation, as per [the API](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/), so there is no point using promises for that.

For initializing the library see [Where should I initialize pg-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382796/where-should-i-initialize-pg-promise).

See also:

- [Verify database connection with pg-promise when starting an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120435/verify-database-connection-with-pg-promise-when-starting-an-app).